# Custom seekbar with material design

Tags: android, material-design

I've got a seekbar in a layout for a custom dialog preference. I changed my styles.xml to use the new material desing. It works because it change text and checkboxes of my settings but I can't apply the color to my seekbar. It works only if I put a seekbar in an activity, it means I have to do something in my custom layout but I don't know what. I post styles.xml and the layout with the seekbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">

        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!-- your app's branding color (for the app bar) -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#FFFF4444</item>
        <!-- darker variant of colorPrimary (for status bar, contextual app bars) -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#FFCC0000</item>
        <!-- theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#FFFF00</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>

</resources>
```

custom layout for dialog preference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

> *With Lollipop it's no more needed at all. The colors are applied well
>   even in custom preference dialogs* ~greywolf82

I want to share few custom Libs

[image]

You can use this **[Material Design lib](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary)** ,this also includes many other widgets.

or

[image]

Custom seek bar Lib [**DiscreteSeekBar**](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar)

Comment: With Lollipop it's no more needed at all. The colors are applied well even in custom preference dialogs.

Comment: @greywolf82 you mean  the new Appcompat lib will does that? looking at the support up to 2.3 ?

Comment: Yep, even if the Appcompat support is limited, but with lollipop works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the android:theme attribute on your SeekBar element. Instead, you should set up the default dialog and alert dialog themes in your AppBaseTheme:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    ...
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppAlertTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#FFFF4444</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#FFCC0000</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#FFFF00</item>
</style>

<!-- This should extend Theme.Material.Dialog.Alert, but that style was
     incorrectly hidden in L-preview. It will be fixed in a future release.
     You can approximate the style using the last two MinWidth attributes.-->
<style name="AppAlertTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#FFFF4444</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#FFCC0000</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#FFFF00</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">65%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">95%</item>
</style>
```

Comment: do you know if it's possible something like that even for holo? colorAccent is a Material item, I can't find anything for holo. Thanks.

Comment: You can do it programmatically by setting a PorterDuffColorFilter on the drawable (see Drawable.setColorFilter), but not from XML.

Comment: Just tried your solution, but it doesn't work at all. Material.Dialog.Alert doesn't exist. And all dialogs with my seekbar still uses the blue holo. I think the problem is the dialog preference, it uses the default constructor of AlertDialog without specifying the theme, in this particular case, the override doesn't work at all.

Comment: Sorry, you are completely right, it is a bug in dialog preference. It has been fixed internally but is broken in lmp-preview release. Same with the Alert dialog theme being public.

Comment: Can you share a link to see the internal fix? Just curious :)

Comment: I was mistaken, the bug was with dialogPreferenceStyle not being loaded but this shouldn't affect the dialog theme. You should still be able to override alertDialogTheme in your app/activity theme to get the desired effect. See the updated answer.

Comment: Actually my custom view with the posted layout is used in a custom dialog preference.

Comment: Could you add code for how you're adding the custom view to the dialog?

Comment: I'm not doing anything special. I've got a class that extend DialogPreference and I call setDialogLayoutResource() in the constructor to use the layout. What information you need?

Comment: DialogPreference.onCreateDialogView() uses the theme resolved from android:attr/alertDialogTheme, so the above snippet ought to work as long as there are no android:theme overrides being used.