# How to make numeric seekbar with Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, android-seekbar

I'm trying since many days to make a seekbar which on Seeking shows a bubble with progress inside it.
As shown here in Google Design:
[Sliders](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/sliders.html#)

I'm also having difficulties in making Looks of Seekbar as shown in Google Design Guidelines

Comment: I found this library.

[Discrete Seek Bar](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar)

It pretty much satisfies me

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476072/custom-seekbar-with-material-design

Comment: you have found the right lib